# Using SVG files with cocos2d v3.x

Tags: iphone, graphics, svg, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to use `SVG` files for graphics with cocos2d v3.x, [Found this link](http://forum.cocos2d-iphone.org/t/ccsvg-display-svg-images-in-cocos2d/1259) but Its not working with the latest version.

Anybody knows how can I use SVG with the latest version of cocos2d.

Comment: This would be nice, especially since there Apple is going crazy with resolutions

Comment: Any luck with this?  Did you think it through and decide to stick with png?  I was curious if storage of an SVG might be less data a png in certain cases.  In other cases however SVG might be bad because the processor will need to constantly render many equations to represent the curves.

Comment: Can't make up anything yet :( still using png for it